# Unicast storm alerts

Tags: windows-server-2003

Hosting company network tech tell me that they detect "Unicast storm alerts" coming from my dedicated server. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a Cisco-ism. Per [Cisco](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-4385), "storm control" is:

> Storm control, or traffic suppression, monitors packets passing from an interface to the switching bus and determines if the packet is unicast, multicast, or broadcast. The switch counts the number of packets of a specified type received within the one second time interval and compares the measurement with a pre-defined suppression-level threshold.

Basically, your server is sending enough traffic in a one second as to trip the hosting company's storm control alarm. If they can tell you you what their threshold values are you may be able to configure some application-layer rate limiting to stay under their storm thresholds.